# inserting data into table from string with splitting

Tags: sql, asp.net, xml

I am trying to insert the XML string like
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,,1,1,1,1,2,23,4
 into a table [image]

I wanted to insert the data into following table in a such manner that after every 3 values it should go into next row is it possible do this?
and the xml string is generated in the program.

Comment: Please post your code **as text** - not as a picture - here!

Comment: Do you mean CSV (not XML)?

Comment: Hi, I just saw that you were on SO shortly... Did my answer not help you? Do you need any further help?

Comment: Thank you for your help it was helpful ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear, but you might be looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @Numbers VARCHAR(MAX)='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,,1,1,1,1,2,23,4';

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT A.B.value('.','int') AS Number
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowInx
    FROM (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@Numbers,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS Casted(AsXml)
    CROSS APPLY Casted.AsXml.nodes('/x') AS A(B)
)
,Extended AS
(
    SELECT (RowInx -1 ) / 3 AS Rank3
          ,Number
          ,REPLACE('Field_' + CAST((RowInx % 3) AS VARCHAR(1)),'_0','_3') AS ColumnName
    FROM Splitted
)
SELECT p.*
FROM Extended
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Number) FOR ColumnName IN(Field_1,Field_2,Field_3)
) AS p
```

The result (btw: the empty value in your example "...8,9,,1,1" is taken as "0"):

```
Rank3   Field_1 Field_2 Field_3
0       1       2       3
1       4       5       6
2       7       8       9
3       0       1       1
4       1       1       2
5       23      4       NULL
```